# Exporting data to text with surrounding tags

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have this Access database (data is also available in .xlsx) that i would like to export data from to plain text with surrounding html tags. It's been 10 years since i've worked with (basic) Access and have no programming experience. The data needs to be formatted like this:

```
<h2>"Cell 2"</h2>
<p>"Cell 4", "Cell 3"<br />
"Cell 5"<br />
"Cell 6"<br />
"Cell 7", tel: "Cell 8"<br />
"Cell 9", "Cell 10"</p>
```

Is this at all possible? How would i go about this? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a Mail Merge in Word. The Merge Source would be the Access table (or Excel sheet), the Merge Template would look like this

```
<h2>«Cell 2»</h2>
<p>«Cell 4», «Cell 3»<br />
«Cell 5»<br />
«Cell 6»<br />
«Cell 7», tel: «Cell 8»<br />
«Cell 9», «Cell 10»</p>
```

where the items enclosed by angular quotes (`«` and `»`) are Merge Fields, not literal text.

Once the merge has been set up and run as "Merge To New Document" you can `Save As...` to save the document as a text file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your reply, will check this tomorrow and update.